# How to create options with icon, text and background color in HTML?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to create a combobox/select with multiple items/options, which contains for each element an icon, text and a background color. I found this [library](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick), which is very good, which solves just two problems of my questions. I want to add also a background, which can change, for the type of the element of the combobox. How Can I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For different background colors of each element you have to create individual background color classes for every element in this [library](http://designwithpc.com/Plugins/ddSlick.)

Comment: The problem is that under Mac Os, the background color for option doesn't work correctly !

Comment: Can you wrote the code, with a simple, but full explained example ?

Answer (score -1):

**This is just a demo example you can try this with your code.**

```html
<html>
<head>Title</head>
<style>
ul li{line-height:40px;list-style:none;}
ul li a{color:#fff;padding:10px;text-decoration:none;}
ul li a.red{background-color:red;}
ul li a.green{background-color:green;}
ul li a.blue{background-color:blue;}
</style>

<body>
  <ul>
    <li>  
      <a href="#" class="red">Red Background Color</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="green">Green Background Color</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" class="blue">Blue Background Color</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want a combobox/select, with option icon+text+background color :)